# How to resolve the red lines in default Confluence plugin pom.xml

Tags: plugins, pom.xml, confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I use "atlas-create-confluence-plugin" to create a Confluence plugin skeleton, and found the pom.xml has many red lines, some are for **project build error** and some are for **dependancy missing**.

As below picture shows, the red lines indicate many errors:
[image]

How could I resolve the red lines since I used the official command to create this plugin project and didn't make any modification in the project.

Comment: Hmm strange, I run the command and had no errors. Which SDK version do you use ("atlas-version")? Make sure you use the latest one. I assume you use eclipse? Did you run "atlas-mvn eclipse:eclipse" to build a eclipse project and download the required jars? Just to be sure, run "atlas-mvn eclipse:clean" before. Whats the out put for "atlas-package"?

Comment: Have you got the plugin to run in 5.10. I keep getting error saying Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.atlassian.confluence.themes.BasicTheme not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in my Eclipse, because my Eclipse was configured with m2e Maven Integration for Eclipse.

For example, Eclipse Maven can't resolve the packaging `atlassian-packaging`. You don't have to worry about the `pom.xml` errors because you'll be compiling, packaging, cleaning, etc. thru the terminal/command prompt using the `atlas-mvn` commands.  You don't compile, build, etc. using Eclipse. Eclipse sort of becomes your glorified editor.